# Install JBPM 6.5 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ant, installation, macos-sierra, jbpm

I am facing problems trying to install jbpm 6.5 on Mac OS X. First of all, I could not install it using Ant install.demo.

So I installed it using Ant install.demo.noeclipse, but when I try to start it using Ant start.demo.noeclipse. But it does not start
and shows the following error on server.log:

> 2017-05-24 19:17:21,756 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot:
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException:
>   WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
>   [wildfly-controller-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356)
>   [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
>   [wildfly-controller-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131] Caused by:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace
>   CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag(). at [row,col {unknown-source}]:
>   [137,15] at
>   org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:637)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:200)
>   at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>   [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml_4.java:546)
>   [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:242)
>   [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_4.readElement(StandaloneXml_4.java:141)
>   [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:103)
>   [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49)
>   [wildfly-server-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>   [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
>   [wildfly-controller-2.0.10.Final.jar:2.0.10.Final] ... 3 more Caused
>   by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Received non-all-whitespace
>   CHARACTERS or CDATA event in nextTag(). at [row,col {unknown-source}]:
>   [137,15] at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:614)
>   [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1] at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:487)
>   [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1] at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:472)
>   [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1] at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1174)
>   [woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1] at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152)
>   [staxmapper-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final] at
>   org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:201)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:182)
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourcesExtension$DataSourceSubsystemParser.readElement(DataSourcesExtension.java:630)

I am trying to use mySql as database.
Do you know why does it happen?
Is there any problem installing JBPM 6.5 on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

No, one of my workmates use Mac OS and successfully installed 6.3 on his laptop. While when we upgraded to 6.5 we use Docker instead. Have a try to use docker: 
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/jbpm-workbench/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can configure a MySQL database using this download?

Comment: -Ddb.server.name=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX or localhost
        -Ddb.jBPMDS.name=dbname
        -Ddb.jBPMDS.user=username
        -Ddb.jBPMDS.password=password

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could happen because you aren't using `ant` correctly, so you should configure `ant` and try again.

You can download `ant` from [here](http://www-us.apache.org/dist//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.10.1-bin.zip), extract wherever you want and configure the local environment [look at this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-apache-ant-on-mac-os-x/)

Once it is configured correctly you can reinstall jbpm:

```
ant install.demo
```

Check how [install](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html#d0e616) jbpm

Comment: Miguel, Thanks but I do not think that it is because of ant. I could install it without changing the default H2 database, the only thing is that I installed it without Eclipse. But the problem happens when I try to configure a MySQL DB. Any other suggestion?